# SSMS not able to access VS database permissions issue

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ssms, sql-server-express

I just reinstalled SSEE 2008 R2 and finally have the service running and SSMS is able to open and create databases.

My problem is that I can no longer navigate natively to my websites folder under Visual Studio. I am not sure how this got missed, but I am looking for the correct way to check permissions and enable this access.

When I have SSMS open and click to attach a database I get the Access Denied Error 5.

Can someone please point me to the permissions settings for SSMS and VS that I must have missed during the reinstall to reestablish this access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the solution that worked was to change the log on account for the service to Local System Account, and enable the check box, Allow service to interact with desktop.